# Linux: C: How can I find which thread has crashed

Tags: multithreading, crash

I have a process with 10 threads. I want to find when the process crashes, which thread has caused the crash.
Is there a way to do this at run-time. I mean not after whole process exit.
I do not want to use signal handlers.

thanks,
Prince

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a core file,**

`gdb path/to/executable path/to/core/file`

`(gdb) thread apply all bt full`

will provide you with a stack trace of all threads.

**If you do not have a core file,**

run your executable in gdb with

`gdb path/to/executable`

`(gdb) r`

or if you have command line arguments, the second command would be

`(gdb) r yourarg1 yourarg2`

then, when the application crashes

`(gdb) thread apply all bt full`

**If you want to generate a core file,** before running your executable that crashes you can execute `ulimit -c unlimited` in the terminal in order to set the core file size to unlimited.

**To exit gdb when you are finished,** simply type `q` for quit when inside the `(gdb)` prompt.

Comment: Thanks.But I want to find out this programatically. May be from another running process.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting every of 10 threads into separate process.